# How to access nested data which is a reference data in an array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have this nested data object which is also a reference data. When I try to access it using populate it is showing only the id. I do not want only the id. I also want the details to come along. Can someone please help me on this?

[image: employeesdetails]

This is the EmployeesDetailsSchema which have this employeesinfo property with a reference in it. Now the designation and speciality property as you can see in the image is coming only in ids and not the full details i want the full the details of these two as well as the other fields also.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const EmployeesDetailsSchema = new Schema({

  employeesinfo: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: "employees" 
  },
  workingdays: Number,
  fathersname: String,
  pan: String,
  joiningdate: Date,
  gender: String,
  pfno: String,
  esino: String,
  branchname: String,
  department: String,
  paymode: String,
  bankname: String,
  acno: String,
  ifscno: String,

  //Earnings
  basicsalary: Number,
  extra: Number,
  totalE: Number,

  //Days
  fixeddays: Number,
  presentdays: Number,
  absentdays: Number,
  leavedays: Number,
  holidays: Number,

  //Deductions
  pf: Number,
  esi: Number,
  professionaltax: Number,
  advance: Number,
  absentdeductions: Number,
  leavedeductions: Number,
  totalD: Number,

  //Net pay Details
  netpay: Number,
  inwords: String,
  name: String,
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = EmpDetails = mongoose.model(
  "empdetails",
  EmployeesDetailsSchema
);
```

This is the EmployeesSchema which is reference in the employeesinfo property of the EmployeesDetailsSchema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const EmployeesSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  speciality: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "speciality"
  },
  contactno: { type: Number },
  designation: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "designation"
  },
  alternatecontactno: { type: Number },
  address: { type: String },
  employeeImage: { type: String },
  imageName: { type: String },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});

module.exports = Employees = mongoose.model("employees", EmployeesSchema);
```

And these are the two models which is being reference in the EmployeesSchema

```
//Speciality Type Schema
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SpecialitySchema = new Schema({
  speciality: {
    type: String
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  }
});
module.exports = Speciality = mongoose.model("speciality", SpecialitySchema);
//Designation Type Schema
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const DesignationSchema = new Schema({
  designation: {
    type: String
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  }
});
module.exports = Designation = mongoose.model("designation", DesignationSchema);
```

And this is the get route

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {


 EmpDet.find()
    .populate({
      path: "employeesinfo"
    })
    .then(empdet => res.json(empdet))
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(400).json({ msg: "Error in finding Employees Details" })
    );
});
```

Comment: can you provide a code snippet. Populate is the right approach.

Comment: the screenshot shows your response? Which field do you wish to populate?

Answer (score 0):

Populate usually returns the entire referred document if there is no specific options set. It can be used like this:
`const story = await Story.findOne({ title: 'Some Titel' }).populate('authors');`

See full documentation and further samples: 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Can you have a look at my models now @Simon Thiel

Comment: Hey guys I found out the answer it was                                                             .populate({
          path: "employeesinfo",
          populate: ["speciality", "designation"]
        })                                                                                                                                  I needed to add the path and populate it like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EmpDet.find()
    .populate({
      path: "employeesinfo",
      populate: [
         { path: 'speciality' },
         { path: 'designation' }
      ]

    })
    .then(empdet => res.json(empdet))
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(400).json({ msg: "Error in finding Employees Details" })
    );
```

Also, please have a look at the documentation too as mentioned by Simon.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Can you have a look at my models and route now @Shrnayvi

Comment: Okay, I have edited my answer. Please have a look!! @BakorKharkongor